# Writing contents of char array to .mem file

Tags: c++

I'm in the process of writing a simulation of malloc, memcpy, free, ect and  need to be able to dump out the contents of a char array into a binary .mem file. I was able to get the PID of each process that launches, but don't know how to go about creating and writing to a .mem.

What would be the standard way of going about this?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), sorry: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_ Too be clear, asking for _suggestions_ solely would come up as _too broad_.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the "resource" keyword. I just need someone to point me in the right direction as to how to go about it. Sample code would be nice too, but I'm open to any help.

Comment: I've already mentioned that, your question is still _off-topic_.

Comment: The how would you word it? Am I supposed to say "Write a function for me that creates a .mem file and writes the contents of a char array to it?" I'm just looking for an example so that I can learn and implement it on my own. Different people might have different examples. I don't see how if something can be done in more than one way, then it is off topic. I thought the point of programming is that there are various ways to solve problems. But I digress. Remove the post if it breaks your rules.

Comment: Well, you should show some specific code you have tried, and where you are stuck with it in particular.

Comment: What's a `.mem` file?

Comment: @Mat It's supposed to be a memory dump file that holds the contents of a char array. The values of the char array would be stored in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Ok, so what specific problem are you having doing that? Surely you know/can search how to create and write to a file. Converting chars to their hex representation is searchable too. Combining both is certainly doable. What step is giving you problems?

Comment: @aurora91 So may be you start to explain us how you're intercepting the `malloc()`, `memcpy()` and `free()` calls in your simulation, and which memory model you are using to back up these. Also specify in which situations you want to dump that backing up memory into a file for later diagnosis.

Comment: @Mat I guess the part that's confusing me is that the type of file is .mem. But since this doesn't seem an existing type, it looks like I should just be treating it as a custom file. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm actually writing those myself. I've only done the malloc so far. I'm keeping a char array to represent the memory content, a memory mapping table with the PID, address, and size, and a free list which holds the address and size. I could add some code, but I'm not sure if it will be relevant.

Comment: @aurora91: that's about right, except it's the other way around, if you will. C doesn't care one bit what "high-level" type of file you're writing, it's all the same (with a small caveat for binary vs text files). You use the same functions to write images, movies, text, databases, etc. It's all custom, unless you use a library that handles the actual format for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canoncial way in c++ to output `unsigned char` values in hexadecimal text representation would be:

```
 std::ostream& hexdump(std::ostream& os, unsigned char[] mem, size_t size) {
     std::ios_base::fmtflags oldflags = os.flags;
     os << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
     for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
         os << setw(2) << (int)mem[i];
     }
     os.flags(oldflags);
     return os;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll play around with that. Sorry that I didn't form my question quite right.

Comment: @aurora91 _"Sorry that I didn't form my question quite right."_ There's still [enough opportunity](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36554744/edit) to bang your question right in shape. Just make clear what you're asking about in particular, and remove all of that irrelevant stuff.